# Writing double to stdout using the write function

Tags: c, linux, io, c99

I store `n` double numbers in binary format as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int k = atof(argv[1]);
    int fd = open("./gen-double.bin", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0666);

    for(double i = 1.0; i < k; i *= 1.333)
    {
        write(fd, &i, sizeof(double));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was wondering if it was possible to output them using the `write` function:
I tried the following code which gives me funky characters:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int fd = open("./gen-double.bin", O_RDONLY);
    double i;

    while(read(fd, &i, sizeof(double)))
    {
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, &i, sizeof(double));
        printf("\n");
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

Do I need to convert these numbers to `char`?

### Edit

Done

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int     fd = open("./gen-double.bin", O_RDONLY);
    double  i;
    int     res;
    char    buffer[11];

    while(read(fd, &i, sizeof(double)))
    {
        res = sprintf(buffer, "%.10f", i);
        buffer[11] = '\0';
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buffer, 11);
        printf("\n");
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're writing the binary encoding of the double into STDOUT.

`printf` (which you would normally use) decodes the binary double into text before sending it to STDOUT.

For example: 1.0 is encoded in memory as 3ff0 0000 0000 0000 ([see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format)).

While the text 1.0 is the characters '1', '.' and '0' which are encoded as 0x31, 0x2E, 0x30 ([from here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)).

Comment: It seems that you're writing the binary encoding of the double into STDOUT. I thought, that the doubles could have been magically decoded with the write function. I have to convert them to characters.